# Calculate the sum of the digits using python

Tags: sum, sum-of-digits

I would like to find the sum of the digits using python. when i enter a birth year 1982 the result should be 1+9+8+2 = 20 final total result is 2+0 = 2.

The reason that i am posting this question is i didn't find any simple python solution for this.

This is my code

```
num = int(input("Enter your birth year: "))
x  = num //1000
x1 = (num - x*1000)//100
x2 = (num - x*1000 - x1*100)//10
x3 = num - x*1000 - x1*100 - x2*10
x4 = x+x1+x2+x3
num2 = int(x4)
x6 = num2 //10
x7 = (num2 -x6)//10

print("your birth number is" ,x6+x7)
```

but i am not getting the correct sum value.

Comment: what value are you getting?

Comment: You can do this in one line. =) `sum([int(digit) for digit in '1982'])`

Comment: i am getting 3 it should be 2

Comment: Change `x7 = (num2 -x6)//10` to `x7 = num2 -x6*10`. Nevertheless, your program is rather naive and repetitive. Try to use loops.

Comment: Thanks @BUZZY its works perfectly. I realized what i did wrong :)

Comment: Here is the full working code that i actually try to build http://arunoid.blogspot.ch/2018/02/this-is-python-birth-number-calculator.html

Comment: https://github.com/arunoid/birth_number/blob/master/calculator

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try adding some debug statements to inspect values as your program runs.

```
num = int(input("Enter your birth year: "))
x  = num //1000
x1 = (num - x*1000)//100
x2 = (num - x*1000 - x1*100)//10
x3 = num - x*1000 - x1*100 - x2*10
print (x, x1, x2, x3)
x4 = x+x1+x2+x3
print (x4)
num2 = int(x4)
x6 = num2 //10
x7 = (num2 -x6)//10
print (x6, x7)
print("your birth number is" ,x6+x7)
```

You'll quickly find your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sum the digits of an integer until the result is a one-digit integer:

```
def sum_digits(num):
    num = str(num)
    if len(num) < 2:
        return int(num)
    else:
        return sum_digits(sum([int(dig) for dig in str(num)]))

>> sum_digits(1982)
2
```

Or a simpler version for the case your number is a year:

```
def sum_digits(num):
    return sum([int(dig) for dig in str(num)])
```

Just call the function twice

```
>> sum_digits(sum_digits(1982))
2
```

Comment: Very interesting that the other three answers on this question are all downvoted!

Comment: What are you implying? I didn't downvote the question or the answers.

Comment: If i remove this question completely my stackoverflow  REPUTATION will be 8. But its seems this questions is somehow interesting so i am going to keep this for while in here until someone up vote.